# CAML - How to handle filter?

Tags: caml-query

SP 2010. I have a value "East & West" and list name Region. How do I handle special characters?

here is the caml that breaks

```
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='ActionStatus' />
  </ViewFields>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Region' />
      <Value Type='Choice'>East & West</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a special character issue.

You cannot combine `Contains` element with `Choice` field type.

Try `Eq` element instead:

```
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name='ActionStatus' />
</ViewFields>
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Region' />
    <Value Type='Choice'>East & West</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this blog](http://code2care.org/2015/error-caml-query-containing-special-characters/), it's stating that you wrap your special text in `<![CDATA[ TEXT ]]>`.

So in your situation it would be `<![CDATA[East & West]]>`.

For others that are building CAML queries programically, you can split the string and add your variable as normal.

```
const direction = "East & West";
const camlString = '<Value Type="Choice"><![CDATA[' + direction + ']]>';
```

However, are you sure that your type `choice` is correct and shouldn't be something like `Text`? Normally choice is reserved for drop-downs, from what I recall.